# which data Structure is suitable to store exception without logger in java?

Tags: java, exception, data-structures

my question scenario is i have program in which arithmetic exception but i know how to catch exception.The thing is i need to store exception in some **Data Structure,later i need to retrive,which Data structure is suitable.** Here is my code.

```
public class ExceptionTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 10, j = 0;
    try {

         System.out.println(i / j);
    } catch (Exception ex ) {

         //need to store exception in some DS(which one is best Suitable and why?
         System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
    }        
 }
}
```

Please guide me.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. Can you give some hints on why you want to do this? There might be other ways of achieving it.

Comment: HashMap is sutiable for this case.

Comment: Stack, using this you can also get the order of exception. By the way why you want to store exceptions? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @sandipon,why hash map is suitable,please give me some explonation.+

Comment: @Sarz,i need to store exception ,again i should retrieve exception from data structure and print on console.

Comment: Its key value pair.you store your operation name as a key and exception(exception type and error message) as a value.

Comment: Like i said,Stack which is Last in first out. LINK


http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: @sandipon,i can store it as key value pair,but why hashmap is suitable here?

Comment: its simple,faster and structured data structure.I use my project and easy to use.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973539/what-is-the-main-benefit-of-using-hashmap-in-java

Comment: Main benefit of using HashMap in java? Probably speed. This Container splits its data to lot of "buckets" that contains only elements with same hashcode of key. That way when it needs to find some key-value pair, it dosesn't have to iterate over all its data, but only over elements with same hashcode in key as hashcode of searched key.

Comment: How can we get a exception trace from the pool of exception. in case of ArrayList or LinkedList, it is not valid. May be there has to be a dynamic unique key generated to know where exception occureed and store it in hashmap ?? would this be correct ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have access to start or end elements (`Exceptions`) you can use a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) mostly in form of `stack` or `queue`.

Next up can be `HashSet` which will prep for fast retrieval but out of order traversal.

Comment: nash_ag,among all types of Data Structure ,LinkedList or HashSet is suitable for my above requirement?

Comment: `LinkedList` would help you preserve the order, if that is not important then go for `HashSet`.

Comment: nash_ag,before coming to conclusion could you please tell me your answer is better or (Mital Awachat) his answer is best.

Comment: The other answer gives you an option of `ArrayList` which can be helpful only in case of random reads (performance basis). Again iterating the fact that there is no one best data structure. It depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may maintain ArrayList to store your exceptions.

```
    ArrayList<Exception> exceptionList = new ArrayList<>();
    exceptionList.add(exception);
```

To persist exceptionList you may use ObjectOutputStream.

Full Code:

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExceptionTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Exception> exceptionList = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 10, j = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println(i / j);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //need to store exception in some DS(which one is best Suitable and why?
        exceptionList.add(ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Mital Awachat,is it suitable for my above requirement and best among all data structure?

Comment: Yes, you may store, retrieve and read all exceptions.
I hope following snippet helps:

// RETRIEVING ALL EXCEPTIONS
        for (Exception exception : exceptionList) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
        
        // PESISTING
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
            outputStream.writeObject(exceptionList);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }